# What is (int*)?

Tags: c++, pointers

I was trying to access the private data members of the class. Everything was going fine until I came upon the `int*`. I don’t get what it is. I think it’s something that we can use to create a new memory address.
My code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class x
{
    int a, b, c, d;

public:
    x()
    {
        a = 100;
        b = 200;
        c = 300;
        d = 400;
    }
};

int main()
{
    x ob;
    int *y = (int *)&ob;
    cout << *y << " " << y[1] << " " << y[2] << " " << y[3] << endl;
}
```

Can anyone help me in understanding it?

Comment: google it.. you can find alot in stack overflow

Comment: This is C-style cast.

Comment: How much C++ do you know? It's casting a pointer to an `int*` type. This may break modern aliasing rules (I can never remember) so as a rule probably don't do that. Here you're assuming that the ints are stored as the first few elements of your class, which may or may not be true depending on whether there are any virtual functions in the class or if you're compiling with RTTI.

Comment: `I came up with the`. You have no idea about pointers but you came up with `int *y = (int*)&ob;`? Cool :)

Answer (score 4):

Its a c-style cast to access the memory occupied by the struct x as a set of ints.

It takes the address of `ob`, casts it from 'address of' (ie a pointer to) x into a pointer to int. The compiler happily assigns this cast to y, so you can manipulate it, or in this case, print out the memory blocks as ints. As the struct happens to be a group of ints anyway, it all works even though its a bit of a hack. I guess the original coder wanted to print out all 4 ints without having to specify each one in turn by variable name. Lazy.

Try using a cast to a char* (ie 1 byte at a time) and print those out. You'll be basically printing out the raw memory occupied by the struct.

A good C++ way would be to [create an operator<< function](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/) that returns each variable formatted for output like this, then write `cout << ob << endl;` instead.

Comment: "Lazy", yes, especially that `int *y = &ob.a;` does not require cast and is not a hack. Accessing other members through this pointer is still ugly.